# How do I index a value which is a @relation in a document in FaunaDB?

Tags: faunadb

Is it possible to create an index of a value from a @relation type in FaunaDB? Here is the schema but I just cannot figure out how to create an index for what would be the data.testing.status value.

```
type TestType {
  testing: Testing!
}

type Testing {
  status: PaymentStatus!
  testType: [TestType!] @relation
}

enum PaymentStatus {
  PAID
  UNPAID
}
```

I don't know if the enum is causing an issue? I can't find any documentation on this.

Here is the query:

```
Map(
  Paginate(Match(Index("certificate_remittance_by_remittance"), "UNPAID")),
  Lambda("ref", Get(Var("ref")))
)
```

and the relevant document data:

```
 "ref": Ref(Collection("Certificate"), "302119834927235593"),
  "ts": 1624382777140000,
  "data": {
    "remittance": Ref(Collection("Remittance"), "302119834830766601"),
    }
```

and remittance document:

```
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("Remittance"), "302119834830766601"),
  "ts": 1624382777140000,
  "data": {
    "status": "UNPAID",
    "chequeNumber": "",
    "remittanceOwed": 245,
    "remittanceAmount": 245
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Certainly.

The `enum` portion of your schema isn't causing an issue. If it were, you would not have been able to import the schema successfully.

With your provided schema, note that the GraphQL API has already created a relationship index for you:

```
Get(Index("testType_testing_by_testing"))

{
  ref: Index("testType_testing_by_testing"),
  ts: 1624315929200000,
  active: true,
  serialized: true,
  name: "testType_testing_by_testing",
  source: Collection("TestType"),
  data: {
    gql: {
      ts: Time("2021-06-21T22:52:08.969203Z")
    }
  },
  terms: [
    {
      field: ["data", "testing"]
    }
  ],
  unique: false,
  partitions: 1
}
```

To add an index for the TestType collection, on the `status` field, you'd run:

```
CreateIndex({
  name: "TestType_by_status",
  source: Collection("TestType"),
  terms: [
    { field: ["data", "status"] },
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this. An index was created, however it is not producing any documents. When I query the string "UNPAID" or "PAID" using the Fauna Dashboard on the index it returns no results.

Comment: Can you show me the query that you are using, and one of the documents that should match?

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, but the document data seems unrelated to your GraphQL schema? If you need help with the FQL side of things, it would probably be best to ask a new question.